# How to redirect a person after loggin

Tags: php, http-headers, redirect

I'm using the below function to redirect a person after specific task (eg.: after login, after logout, after searching etc.)
code is below:

```
<?php
class common {
    /* Redirect to another page
     * $url= Url to go
    */
    function redirection($url){
        header("location: $url");
        exit();
    }
    // Some other function below
?>
```

But now I'm dealing this class with many project of different host (MLM project). I have a problem now. With some server it works as i expected, but in some other server, it's not redirecting. If i enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`; i found a notice that `headers are already send`. So I'm in confusion that what can I do now instead of `header()` function. Also i tried the below code

```
<?php
    function redirection($url){
        echo "<div align='center'><a href='$url' target='_top'><img src='../img/proceed.jpg' alt='Proceed>>' align='absmiddle' border='0'></a></div>";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

But it is not desirable as everybody wants automatic redirection. My servers are windows and linux both. Please help me anyone

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are not outputting anything before the `header()` is executed? Also, lookout for the spaces or newlines after the closing `?>` php tags.

Comment: "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file." from http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: if you enable error_reporting(E_ALL), you'll probably get warnings that will be sent to the browser, so that's why you get this error "header already sent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, this situation is very common, then you can simple turn on output buffering (the output will be stored in an internal buffer).

Use `ob_start();` in the very first line of your application

```
<?php
    class common {

        /* Redirect to another page
         * $url= Url to go
         */

        function redirection($url)
        {
          header("location: $url");
          exit();
        }

        // Some other function below

    }

?>


<?php
    ob_start("redirection");

    // Your Common Class Page
    include("Common.php");

     // some code 

    ob_end_flush(); // turn off output buffering
?>
```

Comment: You would probably want to move the ob_start before the include(common.php). As you stated in your answer it should be used in the first line of your app.

Comment: @jdias Yeah, I edited the answer now it is in the right place. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @Indian Girl It is nice if works for you. Like I said it is a common situation, you can go deep a little if you wish, doing some verification (verify if headers was already sent) in your Common class if YES then Turn On Output Buffering otherwise just redirect with headers("Location your_page.php"); If it really help you please accept the answer. Thanks and good luck in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is to test if the header has already been sent before calling header(location). You could use mix both solutions:

```
<?php
class common {
    /* Redirect to another page
     * $url= Url to go
    */
    function redirection($url){
        if (!headers_sent()) {
            header("location: $url");
        } else {
            echo "<div align='center'><a href='$url' target='_top'><img src='../img/proceed.jpg' alt='Proceed>>' align='absmiddle' border='0'></a></div>";
        }
        exit();
    }
// Some other function below
?>
```

This way if the headers haven't been sent, you redirect automatically. If they have, you ask the client to click.

This is the reason why when you see a redirection notice in most websites, it also includes a sentence stating - if you are not redirected automatically, please click here...

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using:

```
header("Location: ".$url, TRUE, 302);
```

If you want to use a different method, or called "refresh" method,

```
header("Refresh:0;url=".$url);
```

Both would work in every case. The problem with your header is, you need to let them know it's a 302 redirect, as well as set **TRUE** to replace the existing headers. If header is already set, you need to replace it using **TRUE** boolean.

302 is also the common HTTP response code for redirection, which needs to be specified when you are trying to redirect using header.

The Refresh method works fine as well, though it has compatibility issues with older browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Actually the first option to pass TRUE will not work. As stated in the manual, the default value is TRUE, so passing true will not change the default behavior. I believe this option was included to deal with changes to headers that you haven't sent yet.

Answer (score 0):

If headers have already been sent, it is likely because content has already been written out to the screen (via an echo, print, or similar). Since your class has no control over what came before it was instantiated and the function was called, it seems unlikely that you can do much to avoid your client PHP (what calls your class) from writing anything out before. Either use Javascript or use [Apache redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

Answer (score -2):

the easiest way is to do it through client side. javascript...

```
window.location= url
```

Comment: Note: To make this work in PHP you might need to use ob_start() and ob_end_flush()... You can read about it here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php